# is there a way in delphi 2009 to make form controls private?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

is there a way in delphi 2009 to make form controls private?  eg:  if i add a label at design time, i'd like for it to impossible for code outside the form to access the label.

(does delphi 2010 have this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design-time controls cannot be made private.  They must be published in order for DFM streaming to work correctly.

Comment: that's been my experience but i had hoped to hear that's changed in d2010 or that there's a way to do that in d2009 that i haven't heard of.

thank you for your answer!

Comment: You would have to instantiate and initialize the controls manally in your code.  But then you lose the design-time support.  Unless you use a third-party plugin/expert that translates DFM contents into compilable source code.  GExperts has such a plugin available.

Comment: thought so.  thank you for your informative comments and for all your work with Team B and SO!

Comment: Since Delphi 2010 has attributes, it would be nice if in future versions the visibility of components in the form designer could be specified by attributes.  For example, a label could be in the private section but have a [DesignerVisible] attribute so the form designer finds it.  I assume the form designer uses RTTI to work so it wouldn't be all that hard at first glance to change it.  Also when upgrading old forms it would automatically add [DesignerVisible] to existing forms.  Anyway, just a thought!

Comment: Yes, the Form Designer uses RTTI to get its information.  Although 2010 introduces a new Exhanced RTTI that outputs information for non-published members, the DFM system is still based on the RTTI of published items only.  Maybe in the next version, that will change, who knows.